# How do I use Flutter persistent_bottom_nav_bar pushDynamicScreen to display a fullscreen modal view?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use an icon button in the appbar to open a fullscreen modal view from one of my PersistentTabViews using the persistent_bottom_nav package. I can open the view just fine from other pages, but when I try this:

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushDynamicScreen(context,
                  screen: SimpleForm(), withNavBar: false);},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
```

...I get an error:

> "_CastError (type 'SimpleForm' is not a subtype of type
> 'Route' in type cast)."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?